# Python generator for "barely obtuse" triangles (Project Euler 224)

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, iterator, generator

I am trying to solve [Project Euler Problem 224](https://projecteuler.net/problem=224):

> Let us call an integer sided triangle with sides *a* ≤ *b* ≤ *c* *barely obtuse* if the sides satisfy *a*<sup>2</sup> + *b*<sup>2</sup> = *c*<sup>2</sup> - 1.
>
> How many barely obtuse triangles are there with perimeter ≤ 75,000,000?

For large `v_max` and `v_max_n`, the generator below yields very slow when I have 750000000 and 500000000, respectively. Having tried for days, I am still looking for an algorithm that can do this in under a minute.

```
from itertools import product
import math

n = 15 * 10 ** 8
v_max = math.floor(n / 2 - 1 / (2 * n))
v_max_n = n // 3

(i for i in product(range(2, v_max_n + 1, 2), 
                    range(2, v_max + 1, 2), 
                    range(3, v_max + 1)) 
 if i[0] <= i[1] and i[1] <= i[2] and sum(i) <= n and
 i[0] ** 2 + i[1] ** 2 == i[2] ** 2 - 1)
```

I have tried using it as `map(lambda x: x, gen)`, nested for loops, and have generally been racking my brain to no avail.

I tried re-writing b, c as expressions. This tends to be quick but misses some of the triples.

```
n = 12
v_max = math.floor(n / 2 - 1 / (2 * n))
v_max_n = n // 3
j = 0  # tested this with low n and compared: 12, 150 to see 
for a in range(1, v_max_n + 1, 1):
    b = (n ** 2 - 2 * n * a - 1) / (2 * (n - a))
    c = (a ** 2 + b ** 2 + 1) ** 0.5
    if c % 1 == 0 and b % 1 == 0 and a + int(b) + int(c) <= n:
        # print(a, int(b), int(c))
        j += 1
print(j)
```

Comment: For me this does not even fit into memory (16 GB). Which is weird, since `product` should not make any intermediate lists and neither should `range`...

Comment: @Graipher you should just get a generator object when you initialize the generator which shouldn't use any memory

Comment: I agree. Yet it does consume memory on my machine (even with Python 3.6.3).

Comment: @Graipher I am on 3.6.6 Anaconda on Mac. Only 8 GBs of RAM, I checked my memory when creating the object but didn't have that problem.

Comment: Very weird, will investigate that later. That shouldn't matter for your question, though. Anyways, can you actually define `v_max_n` and `v_max` in your code? Also, `n` does not seem to have anything to do with the rest of the code.

Comment: @Graipher sum(i) <= n. Added the variable definitions.

Comment: `... and i[0] ** 2 + i[1] ** 2 == i[2] ** 2 - 1` Can't you calculate `i[2]` directly instead of testing all possible values?

Comment: @tobias_k of course but then our product is larger. Not sure if that would be faster or slower though.

Comment: @tobias_k Improvement is very small for small n and yields the same results for large n.

Comment: It would probably help to tell what problem you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @Josay See comment below my answer: [Project Euler #224](https://projecteuler.net/problem=224)

Comment: @Josay I'm not sure I agree with that edit of the title. The original question asked for "optimizing this generator", which is technically not the same as "solve this problem". E.g. my answer certainly makes the generator faster (and those general hints are applicable to similar problems, too), but it's still far from solving the Project Euler problem.

Comment: @tobias_k Fair enough, I'm happy to see a more precise name but the original name clearly conveys no intent about what the code is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Josay Agreed. Maybe "Optimizing generator for solving Project Euler #224" or something like that?

Comment: @tobias_k This is fine for me. Also, if your optimised solutions is still far from solving the PE problem, I reckon the question should be closed as "code not working".

Comment: "Looking to run it under a minute" might be impossible depending on the specs of the computer you're using.

Comment: @IEatBagels according to the website, a modestly powered computer can accomplish this task.
https://projecteuler.net/about

Comment: A running time "under a minute" (or in a few minutes, but somewhere in that ballpark) is certainly possible, but _not_ using a brute-force-search over (10^6)^3 possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to find a solution for `a²+b²=c²-1` with some added constraints, like `a<=b<=c`, `a+b+c<=n`, etc. by trying *all* possible combinations of `a`, `b`, and `c` and testing whether they satisfy all your conditions at once. This is pretty wasteful.

Instead of `itertools.product`, you can use a generator expression with three regular `for` loops. This has several advantages:

- you could move some of the `if` clauses up after the first or second loop, i.e. you don't have to run the other loops if those conditions already fail at this point, e.g.

  ```
   for x in ... if test(x) for y in ... if test(y) ...
  ```
- you can use the values of your previous variables in the lower and upper bounds for the later variables (in your case this replaces most of your `if` conditions)
- you can basically *calculate* the value for `c` from `a` and `b` without testing all possible values

This is how I'd do it:

```
gen = ((a, b, int(c))
       for a in range(2, v_max_n + 1, 2)
       for b in range(a, min(v_max + 1, n - a - a), 2) # use a for lower and upper bounds
       for c in [(a ** 2 + b ** 2 + 1)**0.5]           # just a single candidate for c
       if  c % 1 == 0)                                 # whole-numbered c found?
```

Note that the calculation of `c` using `very_large_number**0.5` might be imprecise with `float`; using `decimal` might work, though. However, even with those optimizations, testing much fewer values than your original loop (on the order of O(n²) instead of O(n³)), it might not be feasible to find solution for large values of `a`, `b` and `c`.

Also note that I did not thoroughly test this for off-by-one errors, since performance was the main concern.

Another thing that you might try: Invert the loops for `a` and for `b`, i.e. instead of testing all `b` for each `a`, no matter how large the difference, test all `a` up to `b` first. This does not decrease the number of combinations to test, but it seems to yield much more valid combinations in the "smaller" number much faster. Like this (upper bound for `b` can probably be reduced):

```
       for b in range(2, v_max + 1, 2)
       for a in range(2, b+1, 2)
```

Comment: It is feasible to find solutions for large N people have solved it with many languages just not an easy task.
https://projecteuler.net/problem=224

Comment: @dustin Surely it is possible, but certainly not using three nested loops with ~10**18 combinations. I don't know what those folks were using, but probably some high-level fancy math.

Comment: I tried all kinds of equation re-written and have like 10 code snippets. This generator one was over 1000x better at lower n but just couldn't hang as n increased.

Comment: I think you need to look at the math more. One thing that will help is that you can put upper bounds on how high to search for one of the numbers based on the gaps between consecutive squares.

Comment: @OscarSmith That sounds like a great idea, but IMHO that's beyond the scope of my answer. My main point was "using individual loops with adaptive bounds and if checks in between is faster than product with lots of checks for each combination".

Comment: yeah I don't disagree. I'm seeing if I can get an answer up that uses this now.

Comment: Re "*probably some high-level fancy math*": not really. A lot of people solved it using an algebraic identity which I was taught at age 12 or 13.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> v_max_n = n // 3
> ```

The name of this variable is a mystery to me, but you seem to be using it as an upper bound on \$a\$. You can get a notably better upper bound on \$a\$ very easily: since \$a \le b\$ and \$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 1\$, \$a + b + c \ge 2a + \sqrt{2a^2 + 1} > 2a + \sqrt{2a^2} = (2 + \sqrt 2)a\$. Then your upper bound on \$a\$ can be reduced by 12.13%.

---

Given a value of \$a\$, the constraints on \$b\$ are \$a \le b\$ and \$a + b + \sqrt{a^2+b^2+1} \le n\$. Rearrange and square: \$a^2 + b^2 + 1 \le n^2 + a^2 + b^2 - 2an +2ab -2bn\$ or \$b \le \frac{n^2 - 2an - 1}{2n - 2a}\$. I'm not sure why you appear to be using this *bound* as a *forced value* in the code you added to the question.

---

$$\sum_{a=1}^{\frac{n}{2 + \sqrt 2}} \left(\frac{n^2 - 2an - 1}{2n - 2a} - a\right)
= \left(\sum_{a=1}^{\frac{n}{2 + \sqrt 2}} \frac{n^2 - 2an - 1}{2n - 2a}\right) - \frac{n(n + 2 + \sqrt 2)}{2(2 + \sqrt 2)^2} \\
= \frac{n^2 + 1}2 \left(\psi\left(\frac{n}{2 + \sqrt 2}-n+1\right) - \psi(1-n)\right) + \frac{n^2}{2 + \sqrt 2} - \frac{n(n + 2 + \sqrt 2)}{2(2 + \sqrt 2)^2} \\
= \frac{n^2 + 1}2 \left(\psi\left(1-\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2 + \sqrt 2}n\right) - \psi(1-n)\right) + \frac{(3 + 2\sqrt 2)n^2 + (2 + \sqrt 2)n}{2(2 + \sqrt 2)^2} \\
> 0.9n^2
$$
The step from the sum to an expression in terms of the digamma function is courtesy of Wolfram Alpha.

As a rule of thumb, you don't want to be repeating a loop body \$10^{12}\$ times, so looping over all values of \$a\$ and all values of \$b\$ is a non-starter.

---

Hint: try rearranging \$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 - 1\$.

Answer (score 1):

One improvement over @tobias_k s answer is to add the extra upper bound on b of `b<1 + a*a//2`. This is valid because after that, the distance between `b^2` and `(b+1)^2` will be bigger than `a^2`, so `c^2` does not exist. This provides a massive speedup at least a first.

Comment: Did you actually test this? Try 10 ** 3. On my machine, it has poorer performance

Comment: Nice. That's a _massive_ speedup, but it still takes ages until `a` gets anywhere close to it's upper bound. (Did not thorougly check whether this actually does not skip any values, though)

Comment: @dustin How did you add that "extra check"? I added it to the `min`; did you do something else?

Comment: @tobias_k I am using timeit for this edit. I added to the min as you say and your solution is still faster without it by 2.3ns and a smaller std. Also, beyond 10 ** 3, it is still going over a minute and I end up stoping the interrupt since it is running very long.

Comment: @dustin "faster by 2.3 ns" is nothing. I did not test it, but maybe the condition is not triggered very often for small n so the additioal check adds a tiny amount of computational overhead without much use. How are you printing your results? Are you getting all the valid results first, or printing them as they come? As I said, waiting for all results still takes ages (after some time, `a` barely climbed into the lower 1000s) , but the individual results come in much faster.

Comment: @tobias_k incrementing a counter but not printing, displaying, or storing the results

Comment: this will mainly help when n is massive. Since the other cutoffs in the min are based around n-something, what this does is it prevents you from needing to search almost all b values for smallish a. Specificially with `n=1.5*10**9`, it cuts off `b>5000`, for `a=100` instead of `b=10**9`

Comment: @dustin Try printing the counter (or the actual element) when you increase the counter, not just when you finished the generator, then you should see a speedup.